# Do I need to pin an array always in C#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, visual-studio

I have some functions created in a C++ project in VC++ such as:

```
// Basically the power is an array
int read_power( int * power, int iByteNumToRead);
```

Now I need to create C# equivalent/wrappers for these functions to be used in a C# project by compiling the C++ code in DLL Library and using to link against the C# functions declared. It ends up being something like this:

```
 [DllImport("my_lib_dll.dll",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 unsafe public static extern int read_power( int * power, int iByteNumToRead);
 public static int read_power_cs( int[] power, int iByteNumToRead )
 {
         if (power.Length < iByteNumToRead)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Error: iByteNumToRead should be <= size of array[]");
             return -1;
         }

          //Pinning the array
          unsafe
          {
              fixed (int* ptr = power)
              {
                  return read_power_cs( ptr, iByteNumToRead);
              }
          }

 }
```

The question here is: Do I need to pin the array before going into C++ function? IS there a need to do that? I understand we do that so that garbage compiler doesn't decide to delete the array but is it needed here? Or can I just get away with declaring the C# function without a wrapper as such:

```
[DllImport("my_lib_dll.dll",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int read_power( int[] power, int iByteNumToRead);
```

Note this has been tested and works. I just can't seem to understand if pinning the array is needed or not? Can someone please clarify as I'm new to the world of C#.

Thanks

Comment: What is *pinning an array*?  I've programmed in C# but haven't heard the term.

Comment: Fixing it location in memory. This means the garbage collector will not move it around.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews please read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement). "Pinning" does not allow GC shift objects in memory

Comment: Pinning is required. Without that GC can move your `power` object in other memory location (during compaction phase). I hope someone can explain it better

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/copying-and-pinning) no pinning is necessary. The data will be either pinned internally or a copy will be passed on.

Comment: @C.Gonzalez Can you please elaborate on why/how it is not required to pin data?

Comment: From the doc linked in my comment:Pinning temporarily locks the data in its current memory location, thus keeping it from being relocated by the common language runtime's garbage collector. The marshaler pins data to reduce the overhead of copying and enhance performance. The type of the data determines whether it is copied or pinned during the marshaling process. Pinning is automatically performed during marshaling for objects such as String, however you can also manually pin memory using the GCHandle class.

Comment: p/invoke will pin data as necessary. you do not need to do it yourself, at least not in the type of scenario you describe, as long as p/invoke is aware that you're passing a managed array (i.e. the declaration of the unmanaged function uses an array type). See marked duplicates for details and examples.

Comment: When the memory is allocated in C# before it is passed to the c++ function then you do not need to pin it. This is because the memory is managed by C#.