# Can I modify (fill) array that I pass from C# to C++?

Tags: c#, arrays, interop, dllimport, native-code

I have the next C# method:

```cs
internal static class FillArrayApi
{
    [DllImport("NativeLibrary.dll", EntryPoint = "fill_array")]
    internal static extern void FillArray(byte[] array, int length);
}
```

It is implemented in the native code like this:

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void fill_array(uint8_t* array, int length);

void fill_array(uint8_t* array, const int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

I use the native code to fill a managed array like this:

```cs
internal static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var array = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        Console.WriteLine("Array before filling: " + string.Join(", ", array));
        FillArrayApi.FillArray(array, array.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Array after filling: " + string.Join(", ", array));
    }
}
```

The full implementation is [here](https://github.com/yaskovdev/sandbox/blob/master/DotNetCppSandbox/FillArraySandbox/Program.cs).

`FillArray` indeed fills my array with `1`s. Is this a proper way to fill the array in the native code or I am just lucky that it works?

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshalling-for-arrays) I can see that sometimes `MarshalAs` attribute is needed, also I have to use `Out` attribute in some cases. Do I have to use them in my case as well or it is fine to rely on the default behavior?

**Edit:** posted the whole code and unhardcoded the array length as suggested in the comments.

**Edit #2:** the return type of `FillArray` should be `void` of course, because the native function is `void`.

Comment: The byte[] array is "blittable", an expensive word that means that no copying is required.  Arrays of simple types (except bool and char) can be passed by simply temporarily pinning the array and passing a pointer to the first element.  Do note that you got the return type wrong and that this code is very dangerous.  The native code can easily write beyond the array bounds, diagnosing a corrupt GC heap is never simple.  Fix that by passing the array length as an extra parameter, as you'd do in responsible C code.

Comment: Please post all your relevant code as copy-pasted text, not links. Also it seems like you do not pin the array before passing it to the native code (see the comment above).

Comment: You are lucky you  didn't get an exception because you are only filling with 5 integers.  There is nothing in the code that is allocating memory to the array and with a larger array you will get an exception.  You either have to allocate the memory in c# or use the Window Allocate method so the allocated memory will be recognized by both c++ and c#.

Comment: @wohlstad, thank you for the suggestion, updated my question. Are you sure the pinning is needed though? If [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46243653/1862286) is accurate, P/Invoke must pin the array for me.

Comment: @jdweng, thank you for your comment. I've updated my question to not hardcode the array length as it indeed may lead to issues. Are you sure that nothing is allocating memory for my array though? Isn't `var array = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }` making the allocation?

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you, fixed the hardcoded array length.

Comment: You are allocating the memory in c# which is not what is used in c++.  You need to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal?view=net-7.0#system-runtime-interopservices-marshal-allochglobal(system-intptr)   c++ uses unmanaged memory while c# uses managed memory.

Comment: @yaskovdev I thought it was required, but after reading a bit more I am not sure. It's probably dependent on the way you specify the p/invoke declarations (see the answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DllImport` definition is wrong.

It should have

- `CDecl` calling convention
- `void` return type
- `[Out]` on the array, as well as `MarshalAs` with a `SizeParamIndex`.

```cs
[DllImport("NativeLibrary.dll", EntryPoint = "fill_array", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.CDecl)]
internal static extern void FillArray(
  [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1] byte[] array,
  int length);
```

While `[Out]` is not necessary in some circumstances (when the array is pinned), it is advisable to add it anyway. [The docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshalling-for-arrays):

> With pinning optimization, a blittable array can appear to operate as an In/Out parameter when interacting with objects in the same apartment. However, if you later export the code to a type library used to generate the cross-machine proxy, and that library is used to marshal your calls across apartments, the calls can revert to true In parameter behavior.

`[MarshalAs]` is necessary here for the same reason. While the default type will be `LPArray` anyway, `SizeParamindex` is needed for marshalling the array back.

Again, if pinning is used then it wouldn't be necessary, but that doesn't always happen. So if you are sure you will never do a cross-process (or cross-COM-apartment) call, only then you can leave off `[Out]` and `[MarshalAs]`.